# Porque mi código java no funciona?

Tags: java

Alguien que me diga porque mi código no funciona y como debo corregirlo ,lo realice pero no logro interpretar el error.

Me sale error en:  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
 public class sar1152694517g
{

    public static void  main (String[] args)
    {
        String nombre;
        float n1,n2,n3,n4,suma=0,definitiva=0,perdio=0,mayor=n,menor=n,contM=0,diferencia,contnombres=0;
        n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Ingrese el numero de estudiantes "));

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante " + i);
            n1=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 1" + i));
            n2=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 2" + i));
            n3=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 3" + i));
            n4=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 4" + i));
            suma= n1+n2+n3+n4;
            definitiva=suma/4;

            if(definitiva>=3)
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La nota definitiva de " + nombre.toUpperCase() +" es igual a  " + definitiva);
            }
            else
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La nota definitiva de " + nombre.toLowerCase() +" es igual a  " + definitiva);
            }
            if (definitiva<3)
            {

            }
            if (definitiva<menor)
            {menor=definitiva;
            }
            diferencia=mayor-menor;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La diferencia entre la nota  mayor y la nota menor es: " + diferencia);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"los nombres que comienza con M son"+nombre.startsWith("m"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"los nombres que termina con A son"+nombre.endsWith("a"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDiogal(null,"El nombre mas largo " +nombre.lenght());

        }
    }
}
```