# Error en mi codigo java, no encontro el simbolo

Tags: java

prodrian decirme que es lo que no funciona en mi codigo  ,no logro interpretar el error ,me sale que no encontro el simbolo

public class prueba{

```
 public static void  main (String[] args)
{
    String nombre;
    float n1, n2, n3,n4;
    float suma = 0, definitiva = 0, perdio = 0, mayor = n;
    float menor = n, contM = 0, diferencia, contnombres = 0;

    n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Ingrese el numero de estudiantes "));

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante " + i);
        n1=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 1" + i));
        n2=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 2" + i));
        n3=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 3" + i));
        n4=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 4" + i));
        suma = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;
        definitiva = suma / 4;
```

Comment: Por favor, trata de no repetir las preguntas. Te recomiendo que borres [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289747/porque-mi-c%c3%b3digo-java-no-funciona) ya que es la misma que la actual que ya te han solucionado.

Comment: Estimado, tiene la pregunta repetida en este foro, ademas ya te dieron la respuesta en tu otra pregunta. tu error es que no tienes definida la variable "n" debería ser algo así int n = 0; https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289754/error-en-mi-codigo-java-no-encontro-el-simbolo

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo no tienes definido el tipo de tu variable n, coloca 
`int n = 0;` despues de tu variable nombre, asi:

```
String nombre;
int n = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Esto debería funcionar:

1. Estas recorriendo con "for" a un "n" que no existe.
2. Escribiste mal "showMessageDialog".

   ```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.lang.*;
   public class sar1152694517g{

   public static void  main (String[] args){
   String nombre;
   int n=3;
   float n1,n2,n3,n4,suma=0,definitiva=0,perdio=0,mayor=n,menor=n,contM=0,diferencia,contnombres=0;
   n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Ingrese el numero de estudiantes "));

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante " + i);
       n1=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 1" + i));
       n2=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 2" + i));
       n3=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 3" + i));
       n4=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota 4" + i));
       suma= n1+n2+n3+n4;
       definitiva=suma/4;

       if(definitiva>=3)
       {

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La nota definitiva de " + nombre.toUpperCase() +" es igual a  " + definitiva);
       }
       else
       {

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La nota definitiva de " + nombre.toLowerCase() +" es igual a  " + definitiva);
       }
       if (definitiva<3)
       {

       }
       if (definitiva<menor)
       {menor=definitiva;
       }
       diferencia=mayor-menor;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La diferencia entre la nota  mayor y la nota menor es: " + diferencia);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"los nombres que comienza con M son"+nombre.startsWith("m"));
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"los nombres que termina con A son"+nombre.endsWith("a"));
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El nombre mas largo " +nombre.length());

   }
   ```

   }
   }

Realiza la comparación con tus líneas de código, aquí (https://www.diffchecker.com/diff) para que observes las diferencias.